# How to select an item in the listbox so that the listbox presents the sub-array for the selected item

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, listbox, listboxitem

I’m still learning the ropes to C# so am unsure of the tools I have at my disposal.

I have a class array of items within a class array of items (eg. carModel[ ] inside carBrand[ ] ...carBrand(netWorth, numberofcars, carModel[ ] ) ... ). The bigger array carBrand[ ] is shown in the listbox on load up.

I want the user to be able to select an item in the list box so that the list box presents the sub-array for the selected item. How do I do this?

Comment: Sorry, but you are going to need to show us some code.  Preferably a Minimal, complete and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We are much better at reading code than at reading your description of what your program does.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 list boxes and do the following

```
class Brand
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Model[] Models {get; set;}
}

class Model
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}


// init your brand list, and model list for each brand
private Brands[] _brands = .  . . 
// init lists
lstBrands.DisplayMemeber = "Name";
lstBrands.ValueMemeber = "Name";
lstBrands.DataSource = _brands;

// then on lstBrands selected intex changed
private void lstBrands_SelectedIndexChanged (sender, e)
{
    if (lstBrands.SelectedIndex = -1)
    {
        lsltModels.DataSource = null;
        return;
    }
    var brand = (Brand)lstBrands.SelectedItem //<-- note - ITEM, not index
    lsltModels.DisplayMemeber = "Name";
    lsltModels.ValueMemeber = "Name";
    lsltModels.DataSource = brand.Models;

}
```

its a little bit pseudo-code but you get the idea - when you select brand, you fill the model lst box with that brand's models that are kept in each brand